# prevent a post back by assigning key function to enter key javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

in the following code, I am using a jQuery call to prevent post back on an aspx page, that is calling Google maps for customer directions. When I use the enter key, instead of the "Directions" button. The page refreshes. I have included a bit of jQuery that should tie the keypress function to the button itself, but it is still causing post back.

My question is, can I prevent post back in this code by binding the keypress function to that button?

Edit 1: I still need to be able to allow the user to press the enter key to execute their search for directions.

jQuery:

```
<script>
        var directionDisplay;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

        function initialize() {
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 10,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.320574, -85.70925),
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                mapOptions);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));

            var control = document.getElementById('control');
            control.style.display = 'block';
            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP].push(control);

            var image = '../images/flag.png';
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(31.239661, -85.499698),
                map: map,
                icon: image
            });
        }

        function calcRoute() {
            var start = document.getElementById('txtAddress1').value;
            var end = "business location";
            var request = {
                origin: start,
                destination: end,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            };
            directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                }
            });




            document.getElementById('map-canvas').style.display = 'inline-block';
        }
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("form input").keypress(function (e) {
                if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) {
                    $('input[type=button] .NavButton').click();
                    return true;
                }
            });
        });
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<div id="control">
            <input type="text" id="txtAddress1" onchange="calcRoute()" value="" style="width: 300px; margin-top:40px; left:10px !important" />
            <input class="NavButton" type="button" value="Get Directions" onclick="calcRoute()" />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return `false` not `true` ... or use `e.preventDefault()`

The default action of `enter` when there is a submit button in a form is to submit the form

When you return `true` the default action will continue but won't when you return `false` or use `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: @charlieftl It seems that this is completely preventing the enter key function from actually being executed. I tested your answer, but cannot get directions when using the enter key.

Comment: Sounds like you are preventing it before triggering the other click or calling `calcRoute()` yourself

Comment: Note you have an extra space in `$('input[type=button] .NavButton')` ... that is looking for a `.Navbutton` that is a descendent of an `<input>`. Removing the space looks for a `.NavButton` that **is** an input

Comment: Then it should read `$('input[type=button].NavButton').click();` ?

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you very much for clearing that up.